# Is it Haram to lie in businesses?

Tags: halal-haram

Assalamu alaikum brother,
I've heard that prophet Mohammed s.w.a.w. has said that lying is forbidden while doing business. Is it about the quality, nature and quantity etc of goods. Because the place I come from here saree business is mean occupation for most of the people. we buy sarees from local manufacturers and export it to other states. To export the sarees to other states you have to say that you have produced those sarees yourself. If you say I have bought it from somewhere else and selling it to you they won't purchase. Because they would consider it to be costlier to purchase from us. it is obligatory to lie  there. So is it fine to say that we have manufactured products ourself?

Comment: Lying is definitely not allowed. It would be cheating

Comment: This is my personal suggestion, please don't consider this as a fatwa and do consult an Islamic Scholar before acting upon it. I think you can get into a contract with the people who you are buying from, this way they will be directly working for you and hence you can say that you are the sole owner of the product.